# Set bars sizes according to data percents

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, coffeescript

I need to create two bar rectangles one near another using data array `[74, 26]`. I have a container that is, for example, 100px height. So I need to make first bar 74px height and second bar 26px to fill in the container.
I suppose I can do this with `d3.scale.linear`, but having something like this:

```
y = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
.range([0, 100])
```

I get one bar as 0px height and another as 100px height which is incorrect. How can I do it properly?

Comment: The first domain value is mapped to the first range value and similar for the second values. If you want a mapping like you've described, it would be `.domain([0,100]).range([0,100])`.

Comment: Thanks! Works great, I just changed second range array value to actual max height I needed.

Comment: Ok, I'll add that as an answer for reference then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In D3 scales, the first value of the domain is mapped to the first value in the range and similarly the second value of the domain is mapped to the second value in the range. For linear scales, the function connecting the two extremes is linear.

So for the example in your question, you would need a scale like this.

```
d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]).range([0,100]);
```